# Apparent close encounter of Inspiration4: Is the airspace cleared for returning spacecraft?

Tags: safety, dragon, entry-descent-landing, collision-avoidance

In the recording of the SpaceX live-stream covering the return of the Inspiration4 crew one can see an aircraft cross path with the capsule [at 22:59:58](https://youtu.be/dpFKNNl47AM?t=3932). This image is a frame grab of the scene seen from a surveillance aircraft:

[image: screenshot from SpaceX video Inspiration4 | Splashdown showing aircraft crossing path]

(The situation is laid out in the image below with data from flightradar24 and my own conjectures.) The video sequence looks somewhat surprising and scary. I have two questions:

- What was the likely vertical distance of the two crafts?
- The coast guard establishes a perimeter to "discourage" boats from entering the splash-down zone. Is there a similar exclusion zone for aircraft? If yes, was it violated in this instance or was it clear that the distance between the two crafts would not fall below the safety limits under any circumstances? Or is the calculated collision risk simply too small to warrant commercial flight detours?

I asked a related [aircraft identification question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/89296/1485) over at aviation which, I hope, is sufficiently distinct.

Edit: With hints from users in aviation I was able to [come up with a scenario](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/89312/1485) that aligns with the available information. Here is an image summing it up. It is possible that Dragon came in from a somewhat more southerly direction but that wouldn't change much.
[image: Aircraft, and wild guess of the line of sight and the Dragon trajectory]

I find two points in this scenario interesting:

- The descent path appears to cross Florida in its last minutes, while the projected path [in the video](https://youtu.be/dpFKNNl47AM?t=1214) shows an approach over Cuba which is less densely populated and, cynics might add, where there is less property to damage. Was the descent over Florida planned?
- The FedEx plane that is likely the one we see passing the line of sight in the video was in a location before the visual pass that would be crossed by Dragon just a few minutes later (where the arrow and the FedEx flight path intersect). Even the altitude of 30,000 feet may be close. Was that an oversight?

Comment: I am almost certain that this aircraft is part of the recovery operations. It looks like the video is shot from the support ship, which would make the aircraft the NASA WB-57 which SpaceX hired to film the reentry. Or, the video is shot from the WB-57 and the plane is either a second WB-57 (I haven't checked how many SpaceX used) or some sort of chase plane. Note that this is no different from how the marine exclusion zone works: obviously, SpaceX's ships are inside the exclusion zone, would you call that a violation as well?

Comment: I agree it's almost certainly involved in the recovery, but maybe not the WB-57. The Canberra has 2 engines spaced out on the wings but the video shows a single exhaust trail from the center of the fuselage.

Comment: @GdD You are right. Also, I didn't notice that the camera has an altitude display, and I find it highly unlikely that GO Searcher has a 20000ft mast to stick a camera on, so it's probably shot from the WB-57 :-D

Comment: This is the WB-57 flight: https://www.flightradar24.com/data/aircraft/n926na#293335de I haven't found a way to search for flights by date and geographical area, unfortunately.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything obvious here: https://www.flightradar24.com/2021-09-18/22:58/12x/28.53,-80.01/9

Comment: There does seem to be something obvious there, @JörgWMittag. The area east of the Cape becomes clear of aircraft by 22:45 -- except for one: N926NA. That plane arrived in the area from the west around 22:00, circled around the area east of the Cape, and left to the west around 23:30.

Comment: @DavidHammen: Yes, but GdD makes a good point: the WB-57 has the engines out on the wings, significantly apart, whereas the aircraft in the video seems to have a single center engine. Also, I am pretty sure N926NA is the one doing the filming. At least according to FR24, N927NA and N928NA weren't flying the whole last week, and the altitude indicator in the video seems to exclude the video being shot from a ground or marine asset.

Comment: @JörgWMittag "no different than marine exclusion": So there is an airspace exclusion zone?

Comment: I believe the landing zone is in international waters and airspace, so there's no authority to create an exclusion zone AFAIK. The FAA would issue a NOTAM, which is a Notice to Airmen which would warn of the re-entry area, it's up to pilots to look at the notices which apply to their course. So it's possible that it was an airplane in proximity without knowing, but given how much area there is I expect it was involved in the recovery.

Comment: The Dragon2 is still in comms blackout due to reentry, thus the capsule is **at least** 30 km and possibly  as much as 50km above that plane.

Comment: @PcMan Ah, that's part of the answer I was looking for. (The other part being how predictable re-entry is, and consequently what constitutes sufficiently safe vertical distances.) You could make it a short answer. (I spent a few minutes to find a flight profile for a Dragon re-entry but only saw those for lift-off, so I wasn't sure at which altitude that ended.)

Comment: At second thought this appears to be an aviation question more than a space exploration one; maybe I'll ask something similar over at aviation SE, with an emphasis on identifying that aircraft and asking about things like international airspace, Notice to Airmen etc.? I have found the people over there extremely good at answering such questions.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: Over at [aviation.se], you will definitely find the ADS-B wizards and FlightRadar gurus who know how to identify wayward planes.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I asked about it [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/89296/1485). I find the visuals pretty spectacular and I'm curious what we will hear :-).

Comment: @JörgWMittag e.a.: I answered the identification part of the question myself: A flightradar24 playback suggests it's a FedEx plane some 18,000 feet higher and 40-50 km away in the southwest, from where the capsule is approaching. Do they have a lens adapter for my Nikon?